# Segment a korean word into individual syllables - C++/Python

Tags: c++, python, string, encoding, tokenize

I am trying to segment a Korean string into individual syllable.
So the input would be a string like "서울특별시" and the outcome "서","울","특","별","시".
I have tried with both C++ and Python to segment a string but the result is a series of ? or white spaces respectively (The string itself however can be printed correctly on the screen). 
In c++ I have first initialized the input string as `string korean="서울특별시"` and then used a `string::iterator` to go through the string and print each individual component. 
In Python I have just used a simple `for` loop.

I have wondering if there is a solution to this problem. Thanks.

Comment: See [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/unicode.html).

Comment: You should find yourself a Unicode string...

Comment: I am sure ICU provides this functionality. (the algorithm is described in the [Unicode Standard Annex #29](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Hangul_Syllable_Boundary_Determination))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Korean at all, and can't comment on the division into syllables, but in Python 2 the following works:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
print(repr(u"서울특별시"))
print(repr(u"서울특별시"[0]))
```

Output:

```
u'\uc11c\uc6b8\ud2b9\ubcc4\uc2dc'
u'\uc11c'
```

In Python 3 you don't need the `u` for Unicode strings.

The outputs are the unicode values of the characters in the string, which means that the string has been correctly cut up in this case. The reason I printed them with `repr` is that the font in the terminal I used, can't represent them and so without `repr` I just see square boxes. But that's purely a rendering issue, `repr` demonstrates that the data is correct.

So, if you know logically how to identify the syllables then you can use `repr` to see what your code has actually done. Unicode NFC sounds like a good candidate for actually identifying them (thanks to R. Martinho Fernandes), and `unicodedata.normalize()` is the way to get that.

Comment: This only works if the input comes pre-composed (And FWIW, that also works in C++ with `U""` strings). As an example, U+C11C can also be represented with the sequence <U+1109 U+1165>, and in that case the first syllable should be those two characters, not just U+1109.

Comment: Fair enough, that's the "I don't know Korean" part. My point is that Python has no trouble chopping up the string of unicode characters. The logic for how to identify Korean syllables is outwith my knowledge. I suppose that the full Unicode grapheme algorithm would do it, although perhaps is overkill.

Comment: Fair enough, I just thought it would be worth pointing out :)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: do you know, would Unicode normalization compose the characters as required, or is there more to it than that in Korean?

Comment: First, let me say I don't know Korean either, I just have an unhealthy liking to Unicode. According to Annex 29, for all well-formed modern syllable the Normalisation Form C would make each syllable be a single character, so that may be a viable option.

Comment: And I while I recommend ICU for doing the same in C++, my library [can handle](https://bitbucket.org/martinhofernandes/ogonek/src/0ed78d1e9788459a9355840563807ee534f7e577/test/so-14624377.c%2B%2B#cl-19) this simple task :) Don't use it on real code, though.